# AngularJS Directive -

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a schedule. The object that I receive from my API is as follows:

```
schedule : {
    id,
    name,
    shifts : []
} 

// each shift is
shift : {
    id,
    schedule_id,
    user,
    tasks: []
}

// each task is
task: {
    id,
    shift_id,
    time_start,
    time_end
}
```

My HTML currently is (please see image below for a snapshot of what it looks like right now)

```
<div class="schedule">
    <!-- This is the time of the day column, such as 10:00, 11:00 -->
    <div id="clock"></div>

    <div class="shifts">
        <div class="shift" ng-repeat="shift in schedule.shifts">
            <!-- The user assigned to this shift -->
            <div class="user" ng-bind="shift.user"></div>

            <!-- This is the time cells in 15min interval -->
            <div class="cells">
                <!-- Not going into detail, but this creates the cells
                <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in cells"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- The tasks -->
            <div class="tasks">
                <div class="task" ng-repeat="task in shift.tasks"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now, since the `tasks` are placed in their own container, then to bring the task down the right start time, I basically calculate how much the `task.time_start` is different than the start of the day, and then convert that to a CSS of `top: $some-pixel` (by multiplying time difference by the height of each cell).

I'd like to instant have these tasks bind to the cells. But how can I do that? The `tasks` are in an array inside `shift.tasks`, and I cannot figure out how I could loop through them while I am creating the cells.

Or maybe what I am doing is right?

[image]

**Edit**

The only thing that I can think of is having the `ng-repeat` inside the cell as well, and use `ng-if`

```
<div class="cells">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in cells">
        <div class="task" ng-repeat="task in shift.task" ng-if="task.time_start = cell.time_start"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehwat depends on features needed. If drag/drop needed for example. I've found it easier to do it the way fullcalendar lays out events, put them on layer above time blocks. Then only dealing with one element for multiple time periods vs multiple elements for one task

Comment: So then you adjust the start time by giving it a margin top or something then Right? Like the way I am doing right now

Comment: or using absolute position...right. Inspect the dom in **[fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)**, might help. If your events don't span columns horizontally will make it a lot easier than a calendar with any duration

Comment: be careful in your ng-if, you should use an equality or identity operator (== or ===) to check, not a single = as this is not a comparison. Same goes for the first answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to loop the 15-min intervals instead of (or combined with) tasks. Create a cell for each, and then check the tasks and if there is a task present at that time - fill the cell.

EDIT

So yeah, basically, what you wrote in your edit - so render both the empty and non-empty cells and fill in the needed ones.

Something like this:

```
<div class="cells">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="cell in cells">
        <div class="subcell" ng-repeat="subcell in subcells"> <!-- 4 subcells -->
            <div class="task" ng-repeat="task in shift.task" ng-if="task.time_start = subcell.time_start"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used `ng-if="task.time_start = subcell.time_start"`, but you can modify it however you want, maybe like `cell.time_start + subcellIndex * 15`, etc...